# Why this code is not working on mobile metamask app while its working correctly with desktop one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am developing a react project in which I need to make sure that the transaction is happening on sepolia testnet  I am using this code to switch and add a network to the given metamask wallet if not present but this code is working fine on the desktop and not in mobile app. when i click make transaction in desktop it prompts me to switch and add network to metamask but in mobile it makes transaction with the selected any network (Eth mainnet in my case ) if i add sepolia manually then it make transaction with sepolia otherwise any other network . any solution ?

```
let acc = "";
  try {
    acc = await window.ethereum.request({
      method: "eth_requestAccounts",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return "Metamask Not Installed";
  }

const chainId = 11155111;

    if (window.ethereum.networkVersion !== chainId) {
      try {
        await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "wallet_switchEthereumChain",
          params: [{ chainId: "0x" + chainId.toString(16) }],
        });
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.code === 4902) {
          await window.ethereum.request({
            method: "wallet_addEthereumChain",
            params: [
              {
                chainId: "0x" + chainId.toString(16),
                rpcUrls: ["https://rpc.sepolia.org" ,"https://rpc.sepolia.dev" , "https://rpc.sepolia.online" , "https://www.sepoliarpc.space"],
                chainName: "Sepolia",
                nativeCurrency: { name: "SEP", decimals: 18, symbol: "SEP" },
              },
            ],
          });
        }
      }
    }
```